# SAPUI5 Understanding manifest.json:rootView and how to assign page to app

Tags: sapui5, manifest.json

I'm trying to develop my UI5 application using JSViews. I want to use the manifest.json file to define the rootView, but I'm not sure where I am supposed instantiate `sap.m.App`, `sap.m.Page` and then where to call `sap.m.app:addPage` & `sap.m.app:placeAt` to render it.

I used https://github.com/SAP/openui5-sample-app as a point of reference on how to construct the application (which is using *XML views* instead of *JS Views*)

In the first tutorial I followed, I created the app & page right in index.html like this:

```javascript
var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"logonPage"});
var page = sap.ui.view({id:"logonPage", viewName:"views.logon", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
app.addPage(page);
app.placeAt("content");
```

But with `sample-app`, the [index.html](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-sample-app/blob/1200f46272acdb6bf3f86807e29f87eb43b7c195/webapp/index.html#L1) file doesn't contain any JS at all - instead it seems that App is created by the [XML view](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-sample-app/blob/1200f46272acdb6bf3f86807e29f87eb43b7c195/webapp/view/App.view.xml#L3), and the App and the view together are loaded as the starting point by the [manifest.json](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-sample-app/blob/1200f46272acdb6bf3f86807e29f87eb43b7c195/webapp/manifest.json#L16)

It doesn't seem right to instantiate the `new app` in the JS View and use `placeAt` inside the `createContent` method. **How are you supposed to do the same with a JS View?**. Am I supposed to leave JS to create the app & pages in the `index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, index.html should not contain code anymore (except the bootstrap script). This is somewhat new, therefore you will find a lot of tutorials which place something like a Shell-Container or, as in your example, a Page directly to the html body.

In your main view, you have to use the mandatory function "createContent" from which you have to return what should be rendered.
Here is the basic implementation of a JS View:

```
sap.ui.jsview("test.Test.view.View1", {
  getControllerName: function () {
    return "test.Test.controller.View1";
  },
  createContent: function (oController) {
    var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
        title: "{i18n>title}",
        content: []
    });

    var app = new sap.m.App("myApp", {
        initialPage: "oPage"
    });
    app.addPage(oPage);
    return app;
  }
});
```

In this case, my "test.Test.view.View1" has to be set as the rootView in the manifest file.

Take a look [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d2f58695fce3476f92fdfc07c9e8f7c6) for more information about how an App is initialized.

Take a look [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f262ef6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) to see the basics of defining a JS View.

Comment: thank you for the concise explanation. Now I'm having the problem that the router is trying to load the app container, but the app container doesn't exist yet per the order of operations in the App Init page you linked. Basically, my app container is now created in the view, but the view loads *after* Component.js:init (which is where the router is init'd). Any insight there?

Comment: Do you call "sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);" in your Component.js before initializing the Router? Is your view, which contains the App Control, set as the rootview in your manifest.json? If you did both, you might want to start a new question with some extracts from your files e.g. manifest, component, index, view. Cheers.